# Proving this continuous function is entire if a related function is given entire

Tags: complex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition, entire-functions

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to think about it. So, I am asking it here.

> Question: Let f be a continuous function from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ such that $f(z^2+2z-6) $ is an entire function. Show that f is an entire function.

As fog is entire where g is $ z^2+2z-6$ . So,$ (f'og )\times g' $ exists for all but how can I use it to verify analyticity of f?

Please help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want a hint??

Comment: @0-thUser yes sure!!

Comment: @0-thUser f'og is not entire as 2z+2 has a zero. But even if f'og was entire then still I wouldn't be able to deduce some conclusion as I don't know how to use analyticity of f'(g) for analyticity of f.

Comment: Complete your argument following my answer, if you want.

Comment: @User Dmitri...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $g(z)=z^2+2z-6$. Now, $g'(z)\not=0$ for all $z\not=-1$. So, for each $z\not=-1$ we can find two small open sets $U_z$ and $V_z$ such that $g\big|U_z\to V_z$ is bi-holomorphic. So, considering $\big(f\circ g\big)\circ \big(g\big|U_z\to V_z\big)^{-1}$ we can say $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\backslash g^{-1}(-1)$. Now, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb C$, so by Riemann removable singularity theorem $f$ is holomorphic. Note that $g^{-1}(-1)$ can have at most two elements.

Comment: Can you please tell which result you used for the assertion " for each z≠−1we can find two small open sets$ U_z $ …  is biholomorphic"?

Comment: Do you mind replying to my question asked in comments?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have forgotten. I will write.

Comment: First, note that $g$ is holomorphic, and for any $z\not=-1$ we have $g'(z)\not=0$. Now, using this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085291/holomorphic-function-is-injective-in-a-neighborhood-where-it-has-nonzero-derivat) for each $z\not=-1$ find a nbd $U_z$ of $z$ so that $g\big|U_z$ is injective. Since, $g$ is non-constant holomorphic $g\big|U_z$ is an [open map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). So, $V_z:=g(U_z)$ is an open set.

Comment: Hence, $g|U_z\to V_z$ is bi-holomorphic by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283713/let-fu-to-v-be-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-show-that-inverse-of-f-is). You may assume, $U_z$ and $V_z$ are connected by shrinking them, if necessary, using continuity.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question(s).